# React having to toggle state twice for response

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm pretty new to React so I made sure to research this as well as I can.
But for some reason when I'm rendering, I have to initiate the state manually for a response.

Here is a portion of it:

```
export class exampleOne extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super();
        this.state = {
            buttonToggleState: true,
            secondToggleState: true
        }

componentDidMount() {
    this.setupPage();
}

buttonToggle() {
    var newToggleState = !this.state.buttonToggleState;
    this.setState({
        buttonToggleState: newToggleState,
        secondToggleState: !this.state.secondToggleState
    });
}

render() {
    return (
         <input type="checkbox" onChange={this.buttonToggle.bind(this)} 
             defaultChecked={this.state.secondToggleState} />
```

It works, just that I have to click the checkbox twice for it to change to actually render. It changes states, just no rendering until the second click, then it works fine after.

Comment: `defaultChecked` doesn't seem necessary there since you are already setting the initial state in the constructor. You can use `checked` instead.

Comment: buttonToggleState and secondToggleState seem to be doing the same thing? Simpler jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/52602/